# Uninstalling a preinstalled python package from Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, huggingface-datasets

[Datasets](https://pypi.org/project/datasets/) python package comes preinstalled  on databricks clusters. I want to uninstall it or completely prevent it's installation when I create/start a cluster.

I couldn't find any solution on stackoverflow.
And I have tried !pip uninstall datasets in a notebook. It throws the below error

```
Found existing installation: datasets 2.12.0
Not uninstalling datasets at /databricks/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages, outside environment /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-some-long-uu-id-I-have-hidden
Can't uninstall 'datasets'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Can someone guide on what to do here ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try deleting in the init script of the cluster ?

/databricks/python/bin/pip uninstall -y datasets